# C++: Allow graceful fails if function is undefined?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I'm writing a testing program for a C++ class, and there are a certain number of member functions that this class is supposed to have. However, the testing script won't compile if the member functions are not all yet defined, since those functions are called in the testing script. Is there any way to allow the testing program to compile but without calling the functions that aren't yet defined? Or perhaps there is another way to get around this problem, for instance by changing how I'm compiling and running my program or by using macros or something like that?

Comment: Just add template <typename T> before each undefined declaration. It might work.

Comment: Templates are not instantiated until you use them, so this way you "lie" to the compiler that your functions are templates. I did not test it though.

Comment: Hmmm, unfortunately my functions already *are* templates.

Comment: And it gives an undefined reference for a template member function? Then you must be using it somewhere in the script already. In this case there is no way around. You should write an empty body for the function and return something if it has a return value.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I am testing other people's code and they complain that my testing code doesn't work when the whole thing fails to compile. Of course it fails to compile if you haven't defined all the things that I am testing for...

Comment: You could use function stubs that do nothing. EDIT: Well, since you aren't the one writing the code, but the TEST, the people writing the code need a kick in the pants to write function stubs.

Comment: Yeah, that's the ticket, I sent out an e-mail about function stubs just now :)

Comment: Sfinae and traits classes.

Comment: Each traits class does a sfinae test to see if the tyoe has a given method.  If it does, it perfect forward calls it.  If not, it throws an error in the forward, which your framework catches.  You call the method through the traits class.

Comment: Yakk, thank you so much. I googled SFINAE and found many SO threads; I have no idea how I didn't find them at first as the questions are nearly identical to mine. Also, I don't know why you wrote this as a comment instead of an answer ;)